# Upload an array on xcode to sql database

Tags: php, ios, sql, objective-c, arrays

I'm creating an iOS app where I create an array. I want the contents of my array to be uploaded into my external SQL database. I think the best way of doing this is to move the array from the xcode into php, once there it can be uploaded into the database. Is this the best way to go about solving this problem? I'm unsure how exactly to do so, so any suggestions would be great, if you could post some example code that would help a lot.

Heres my code for the button that adds to the array

```
-(IBAction)makeEntry:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSString *strEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Entry %d\n",
                      self.entryCount++];
[self.entries addObject:strEntry];
[self makeText];
```

What would the code for the button that uploads the array look like?
And what would the code at the php side look like ?
Thanks

Comment: do you have server running somewhere for your php script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can post data on your php/asp server through this code in iOS:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length]forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; //postData could be your actual data which is NSData .. 
  [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request setHTTPBody:postData];

  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                                delegate:self];

  [connection start];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And then on server side you can perform your SQL data operations.

Comment: thanks okay so i have an array called entries and i have a button that every time it is clicked adds an entry to the array -(IBAction)makeEntry:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *strEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Entry %d\n",
                          self.entryCount++];
    [self.entries addObject:strEntry];
    [self makeText];   Theres the code so I want a button that uploads the array how exactly would it look? and how would the code look on the php side...sorry for all the questions but it would really help